# In ios how to get logged in user info using v2 box sdk?

Tags: ios, iphone, box-api

i integrated ios box v2 sdk with my app. I can do all operations other than getting the logged in user info like name, email and so on. Any one solved this issue?. Please let me know.

There is a class called "BoxUser" but i do not know from where and how to call that class and get the info i want.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There is a function provided for getting the current user info in the sdk :

```
[[BoxSDK sharedSDK].usersManager userInfoWithID:BoxAPIUserIDMe requestBuilder:nil     success:successBlock failure:failureBlock];
```

Comment: I'm the maintainer of the iOS SDK. This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *str =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.box.com/2.0/users/me?access_token=%@",str_access_token];


    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]
                                                  cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowed
                                              timeoutInterval:20];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                               NSData *data,
                                               NSError *error) {

                               if ([data length] >0 && error == nil) {


                                   NSError *myError = nil;

                                   NSMutableDictionary *userdata = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError]];

                               } else if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil) {

                                   NSLog(@"Nothing was downloaded.");

                               } else if (error != nil) {

                                   NSLog(@"Error = %@", error);
                               }
                           }];
```

Comment: BoxOAuth2Session *session = (BoxOAuth2Session *) [notification object];
    NSLog(@"Access token  (%@) expires at %@", session.accessToken, session.accessTokenExpiration);

Answer (score 0):

```
METHOD
GET /users/me

EXAMPLE REQUEST
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/users/me
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

[More](https://developers.box.com/docs/#users)

Comment: this is the api right. I hope that there is a simple way to get using box v2 ios sdk. And idea on that?. Also this requires another http request.

Comment: I think you need to make a new request for user details.